# VBA to Outlook Issue - Don't want Number with Comma

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have a problem with generating Outlook emails through VBA. The problem is that when the VBA exports information from Excel sheet to Outlook, the numbers on Excel sheet will always be translated into numbers with commas, rather than their original formatting in Excel. Please see the codes below. I need to get rid of comma in one cells in column D. Ex. if d is 123456, in Outlook, it will show 123,456 but i don't want the comma.

Thanks!

```
                    dim a , b, c, d, e as integer

                    ActiveSheet.Range("A6").Value = a
                    ActiveSheet.Range("B6").Value = b
                    ActiveSheet.Range("C6").Value = c
                    ActiveSheet.Range("D6").Value = d
                    ActiveSheet.Range("E6").Value = e

                    Set msg_range = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", "E66")
                    Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
                    With MItem
                        .To = toEmails
                        .CC = ccEmails
                        .Subject = email_subject
                        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(msg_range) & "<IMG SRC=""signatures.png"">"
                        .Display
                    End With
```

Comment: I assume you have cells A6:E66 formatted with commas in Excel, and you want it to continue to be formatted that way while in Excel - you just don't want it formatted that way in the email?

Comment: I just tested [RangetoHTML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519602(v=office.11).aspx) and @YowE3K is correct.  `RangetoHTML` accurately mimics the number format of the range.

Comment: @ThomasInzina - Ron de Bruin will be wondering why he is getting so many hits on his website!  (I just tested it too.)

Comment: Lol..I didn't want to overload his site so I got his code from MSDN OfficeTalk.

Comment: @YowE3K no I have not applied a comma formatting in those cells. I have tried to keep it as text, number, general and custom formatting however the issue still persists. Whatever format I keep it in, the comma still appears in the email on outlook. Did you try with 6 digit numbers when you were testing it? Also I have an option compare text in our Macro. Does that make a difference?

Comment: (a) I tested with about 8 digits, formatted with commas, formatted with commas and 2 decimal places, formatted as currency, formatted as accounting, formatted as General.  (b) When your code runs, what is the value of `d` in your code when the cell is written to?  What data type is `d`? (As a Variant, it could be holding a String, or a Double, or a Currency, or an Integer, etc.)  How is the number displayed in Excel immediately after the cell is written to?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have the cells formatted with commas in Excel, but want to use General format for column D when placing it in the email, you could try using

```
dim a , b, c, d, e as integer  ' Note: This command is only declaring e to be integer
                               '       a, b, c and d are being declared as Variant
Dim oldFormat As String

ActiveSheet.Range("A6").Value = a
ActiveSheet.Range("B6").Value = b
ActiveSheet.Range("C6").Value = c
ActiveSheet.Range("D6").Value = d
ActiveSheet.Range("E6").Value = e

Set msg_range = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", "E66")

oldFormat = ActiveSheet.Range("D1").NumberFormat
ActiveSheet.Range("D1:D66").NumberFormat = "General"

Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
With MItem
    .To = toEmails
    .CC = ccEmails
    .Subject = email_subject
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(msg_range) & "<IMG SRC=""signatures.png"">"
    .Display
End With

ActiveSheet.Range("D1:D66").NumberFormat = oldFormat
```

Note:  This will set all cells in D1:D66 back to the format that existed in D1 at the start of the macro.  If various cells had different formats, the code will need to be a bit more complicated.